# I am getting error: RPC failed; fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly on git

Tags: git, github, push, github-for-windows

I want to push some files from local repository to Origin with GitHub desktop app (Windows 10). But again and again showing an error. The error is:

```
Enumerating objects: 26, done.
Counting objects: 100% (26/26), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Writing objects: 100% (25/25), 3.37 MiB | 147.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 25 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Here is the picture of this error:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.

I closed the GitHub desktop app, opened it again and pushed. This time successfully pushed to Origin.

Thank you.